# How can I ensure my ListView is refreshed in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, prism

I received some help yesterday. I am still new to c# and using Xamarin Forms with Prism as the MvvM Framework.

I pull data from an API and want to display it in a ListView, the api works and returns data correctly. If I return the data as a List and bind the list, I have to manually update the binding in the XAML (while running the application) in order to view the data in the rows.

I thought I may need to change to an ObservableCollection, but I didn't have much luck with it.

How can I correct this?
I will try to updated the OP with a gif showing my problem.

Here is my model:

```
    public class OpenWorkOrder
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string WOID { get; set; }
    public string AssetNumber { get; set; }
    public string WorkRequested { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Active { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the ViewModel:

```
    private List<OpenWorkOrder> _openWO;

    public List<OpenWorkOrder> OpenOrders
    {
        get { return _openWO; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _openWO, value); }
    }
        
    private string selectedWO;

    public string SelectedWO { get => selectedWO; set => SetProperty(ref selectedWO, value); }

    private string wOID;

    public string WOID { get => wOID; set => SetProperty(ref wOID, value); }

    private string iD;

    public string ID { get => iD; set => SetProperty(ref iD, value); }

    private string workRequested;

    public string WorkRequested { get => workRequested; set => SetProperty(ref workRequested, value); }
    
    
    
    public async Task<List<OpenWorkOrder>> OpenWO()
    {
        
        var client = new RestClient("apiurl/");
        var request = new RestRequest("Maint/GetOpenWorkOrders", Method.GET);
        IRestResponse<List<OpenWorkOrder>> response = await client.ExecuteAsync<List<OpenWorkOrder>>(request);

        if (response.StatusCode.ToString() == "OK")
        {
            return response.Data;
        }

        else
        {
            return null;
        }
        
    public async void OnNavigatedTo(INavigationParameters parameters)
    {
        try { OpenOrders = await OpenWO();
            Console.WriteLine("Await Called!");
            }
        catch (Exception ex)
            {
            await _dialogService.DisplayAlertAsync("Exception Handled", ex.ToString(), "OK");
            }
    }
    
    private List<OpenWorkOrder> _openWO;

    public List<OpenWorkOrder> OpenOrders
    {
        get { return _openWO; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _openWO, value); }
    }
        
        
    public async Task<List<OpenWorkOrder>> OpenWO()
    {
        
        var client = new RestClient("apiurl/");
        var request = new RestRequest("Maint/GetOpenWorkOrders", Method.GET);
        IRestResponse<List<OpenWorkOrder>> response = await client.ExecuteAsync<List<OpenWorkOrder>>(request);

        if (response.StatusCode.ToString() == "OK")
        {
            return response.Data;
        }

        else
        {
            return null;
        }
        
    public async void OnNavigatedTo(INavigationParameters parameters)
    {
        try { OpenOrders = await OpenWO();
            Console.WriteLine("Await Called!");
            }
        catch (Exception ex)
            {
            await _dialogService.DisplayAlertAsync("Exception Handled", ex.ToString(), "OK");
            }
    }
```

Here is the XAML:

```
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
    <ListView  x:Name="Data" ItemsSource="{Binding OpenOrders}"
               GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding WOID}"
               SelectionMode="Single">
        <ListView.Behaviors>
        </ListView.Behaviors>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label Text="{Binding WorkRequested}" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding WOID}"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

EDIT: Attached gif here

[image]

Comment: this should work, if your VM implements INotifyProeprtyChanged

Comment: Hey Jason, Thank you for helping me yesterday!
 I added INotifyPropertyChanged to no avail, but I was under the impression Prism already handled that with BindableBase.PropertyChanged?

I also noticed I'm binding to (as an example, in the XAML) to WOID, not necessarily OpenOrders.WOID?

Comment: based on your code I had no idea you were using BindableBase.  The bindings in your template will be relative to their BindingContext, which is OpenWorkOrder.  This could just be an issue with HotReload and not your actual code.  Finally, you might try using CollectionView instead of ListView

Comment: I'll swap it over to a collection view, I updated the ViewModel to exclude the WOID (to ensure it would reference the OpenWorkOrder.WOID, but the XAML is showing
"Member not found in Data Context WOOpenViewModel"